# How do update and insert data in one table using the data in another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables `prod1` and `prod2` having same fields (`pid,pname,pprice,pcode`). Have some data in `prod1` table like below

```
Pid     Pname    Pprice  Pcode
---     -----    ------  -----
1       Aaaaa    500     A-1
2       Bbbbb    1000    B-1
3       Ccccc    1500    C-1
```

And have data in `prod2` table like below

```
Pid     Pname    Pprice  Pcode
---     -----    ------  -----
1       Aaaaa    5000    A-1
2       Bbbbb    5000    B-1
3       Ccccc    1500    C-2
4       Ddddd    2000    D-1
5       Eeeee    500     E-1
```

I need to update prod1 table using prod2 table

```
If prid1.pid=prod2.pid
Else
Insert the data into prod1 from prod2
```

Final aim is to store prod2 data in prod1 without delete in prod1
Help me to solve I tried cases and while etc

Answer (score 0):

Finally Solved My Problem
..........................

update prod1
set pname=b.pname, pprice=b.pprice, pcode=b.pcode
from prod2 b,prod1 a where a.pid=b.pid

select * from prod1
insert into prod1
select * from prod2 b
where b.pid not in(select pid from prod1)

Thanks